# How to get setInterval to continue running when on another screen?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is a simple counter https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-sinoussi-rwkfrk?file=/src/App.js:0-684.

If you go to another screen, it stops counting. I want it to continue counting. How?

Code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const [startCounting, setStartCounting] = useState(false);

  const handleCount = () => {
    setStartCounting(true);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (startCounting) {
      interval = setInterval(() => {
        setCount((prevCount) => prevCount + 1);
      }, 10);
    }

    return () => {
      clearInterval(interval);
    };
  }, [startCounting]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={() => handleCount()} disabled={startCounting}>
        Start counting
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I'm thinking local or session storage might be needed is there any other way?

Comment: where is another screen here? Can you replicate your issue in the codesandbox?

Comment: Sorry another screen was unclear. I mean if you go to another tab.

Comment: You mean another browser tab?

Comment: Yes, if you start the counter then go to another tab the counter tab becomes inactive and stops counting until you go back to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can use the Web Workers API to run JavaScript in **background** threads, separate from the main execution thread of a web app. This ensures that the **counter logic** will run even if the tab is inactive. & Rather than incrementing every second, save a timestamp to **localStorage** when the **counting starts.** When you come back to the tab, calculate the difference between the **current time** and the saved timestamp. This way, you can get the elapsed time and update your counter accordingly.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(localStorage.getItem("count") || 0);
  const [startTimestamp, setStartTimestamp] = useState(localStorage.getItem("startTimestamp"));

  const handleCount = () => {
    const currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
    setStartTimestamp(currentTimestamp);
    localStorage.setItem("startTimestamp", currentTimestamp);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (startTimestamp) {
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        const currentTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
        const elapsedSeconds = Math.floor((currentTimestamp - startTimestamp) / 10);
        setCount(elapsedSeconds);
        localStorage.setItem("count", elapsedSeconds);
      }, 10);
      
      return () => {
        clearInterval(interval);
      };
    }
  }, [startTimestamp]);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Count: {count}</p>
      <button onClick={handleCount} disabled={!!startTimestamp}>
        Start counting
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Might be it will work for you.

Comment: Hi thanks this helped me realized how to solve this problem. Why do we need localStorage? I removed all the localStorage usage and the code still seems to work?

https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-dirac-stp7vt?file=/src/App.js

Comment: We are storing it in local storage because when you close the tab then after some time open it in a new tab it starts with the same number when you left with the count. If you don't need this then you can use it without local storage.